# Stop grouping together multiple answers to the same question in user profile

Tags: feature-request, answers, profile-page

If I have provided two answers to the same question, there is only one answer shown in my user profile.  This answer is followed by "(2)", indicating that two answers are there, and the rep shown is the sum of those two answers' rep.  Clicking on this takes you to the highest-rated (or maybe the oldest?) of the two answers.

This is misleading if you are looking at how much rep you got for a given answer because you want to know how close you are to a badge.  It also makes it hard to get to the second answer that was provided.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I agree with this. It makes it almost impossible to find those multiple answers in the same question (whether for yourself or if you are looking for an answer from a specific user who has multiple answers).

Answer (score 4):

I never got this concept. I guess it's based on that you should only have one answer per question.  If you need to add more info, you can edit your answer.

The system is designed that way (ie. it asks you if you're sure you want to add another answer)

It's a side effect of the intended design of the site (to answer a question) and the actual usage of many question (poll / subjective questions with many answers)

Comment: yes, basically these kinds of "poll" questions were never intended -- and I'm loathe to add a bunch of functionality to *encourage* them

Answer (score 0):

What about answers from questions that have been merged (such as from a only-very-slightly different question closed as a dupe)?  I'd love to edit the content of one of my answers into the other, except deleting an answer would mean losing its rep.

So maybe what this means is that **a user should be able to merge two of his answers (including comments and accrued reputation) into one**.  This could be an ability granted after ~250-500 rep, perhaps.

Answer (score -2):

> But it is difficult to find the other answer I provided to this question (this one) which currently has 13 rep.

You can easily find that answer [using the advanced search operators](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search). Of course this question predates those existing..