# Community size of a Stack Exchange site

Tags: support, statistics

Is there a way to see the community size of any Stack Exchange site?

That is, see how many active members there are where an active member might answer or ask questions.

Comment: Very good question. Because if a (sub) site is only visited by 100 people each day, you may want to ask your specific question elsewhere (I am of course not talking about sites like the computerscience stackexchange but more unknown ones that may have few visitors for a high number of reasons, first being they are not very tech savvy)

Answer (score 5):

Since the release of the [Stack Exchange API](https://stackapps.com/), it is now possible to programmatically obtain information from the Stack Exchange network of sites.

---

***General Statistics***

The following are the statistics of each Stack Exchange site which are marked as "normal" by the Stack Exchange API.

The activity on the site could probably be inferred by looking at the "Answers per minute", "Questions per minute", "Badges per minute" and the "Views per day" values.

**Stack Overflow** (http://stackoverflow.com)

- Total Users: 312707
- Total Questions: 865378
- Total Answers: 2289012
- Total Votes: 8048695
- Total Comments: 3366704
- Total Badges: 851977
- Total Unanswered Answers: 145956
- Total Accepted Answers: 539961
- Answers per minute: 2.18
- Questions per minute: 1.1
- Badges per minute: 1.01
- Views per day: 476665.42

**Server Fault** (http://serverfault.com)

- Total Users: 34860
- Total Questions: 47042
- Total Answers: 114263
- Total Votes: 307042
- Total Comments: 141190
- Total Badges: 74178
- Total Unanswered Answers: 8380
- Total Accepted Answers: 23297
- Answers per minute: 0.11
- Questions per minute: 0.06
- Badges per minute: 0.09
- Views per day: 23211.88

**Super User** (http://superuser.com)

- Total Users: 43858
- Total Questions: 48310
- Total Answers: 112316
- Total Votes: 355208
- Total Comments: 165852
- Total Badges: 75282
- Total Unanswered Answers: 8382
- Total Accepted Answers: 24215
- Answers per minute: 0.15
- Questions per minute: 0.07
- Badges per minute: 0.11
- Views per day: 23790.9

**Meta Stack Overflow** (http://meta.stackoverflow.com)

- Total Users: 20010
- Total Questions: 13278
- Total Answers: 37050
- Total Votes: 308055
- Total Comments: 130500
- Total Badges: 35502
- Total Unanswered Answers: 986
- Total Accepted Answers: 6082
- Answers per minute: 0.04
- Questions per minute: 0.02
- Badges per minute: 0.05
- Views per day: 3082.9

**Stack Apps** (http://stackapps.com)

- Total Users: 2898
- Total Questions: 523
- Total Answers: 737
- Total Votes: 4974
- Total Comments: 3398
- Total Badges: 2934
- Total Unanswered Answers: 113
- Total Accepted Answers: 243
- Answers per minute: 0.0
- Questions per minute: 0.0
- Badges per minute: 0.01
- Views per day: 1089.26

---

***Active Users***

Let's define an *active user* to be one defined in [Pollyanna's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37379/community-size-of-a-stack-exchange-or-stack-overflow-site/37388#37388): an user who has more than 100 reputation.

**Edit**

As suggested in the comments by mmyers, I have updated the definition of an *active user* to be someone who has more than 101 reputation points (minimum of 102 points), to account for users who have gotten 100 points by merely associating an account.

It is possible to perform a query on the Stack Exchange API to return users who have a minimum of 102 reputation points.

The results are as follows:

**Stack Overflow** (http://stackoverflow.com)

- Active Users: 39307

**Server Fault** (http://serverfault.com)

- Active Users: 6470

**Super User** (http://superuser.com)

- Active Users: 6908

**Meta Stack Overflow** (http://meta.stackoverflow.com)

- Active Users: 3413

**Stack Apps** (http://stackapps.com)

- Active Users: 176

---

*1) The data was obtained at approximately Saturday, August 14, 2010 1800 GMT.*

*2) Statistics of a Stack Exchange site can be obtained by calling the `/stats` method of the API endpoint. (For example, Stack Overflow would be `http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/stats`.) For more information on using the Stack Exchange API, visit https://stackapps.com/.*

*3) To query users with a reputation greater than 100, one would use the `/users` method with the parameters to `sort` by `reputation` and set the `min` value to `100`. For example, for Stack Overflow, one could query `http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users?sort=reputation&min=100`.*

*4) The definition of what is constituted as a "normal" site is not precisely defined (or at least I haven't been able to find one), but according to [this documentation page](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/method?method=stats), a normal site is one that is non-meta and non-beta.*

*5) Only the sites which were marked as "normal" were included, as the total number of Stack Exchange sites, including meta and beta, were 43 as of the time the statistics were obtained.*

*6) The above statistics data was obtained and formatted by a pre-release version of a Java client I am currently writing for the Stack Exchange API.*

Comment: I think a more accurate metric for active users would be those who have more than 101 reputation. This would eliminate users who merely created an account and associated it without doing anything further.

Comment: @mmyers Thanks for the suggestion! I've updated the definition and the data. It turns out that the active users for Stack Overflow did not change much, but the other site have changed quite a bit.

Comment: @coo, which Java wrapper are you using?

Comment: @coobird: the three rates (X per minute) are quite small for some of the sites. I suggest also listing them in a larger unit, per hour.

Comment: @jjnguy I'm using a client (wrapper) that I'm currently writing. It's still has unimplemented functionality, so I haven't released it yet.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen The rates in the statistics are the raw values returned by the Stack Exchange API -- those are not calculated values. The values returned by the API are in the units that are listed. Changing the unit from minutes to hours to would entail multiplying the obtained value by 60, but it would not accurately reflect the actual usage over some 1 hour period.

Answer (score 5):

You can view the total number of users, daily site visits, and daily question count for any Stack Exchange community on the ["All sites" page](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list).

Below are the top 10 sites by total users as of August 2, 2021:

[image: Sites by user count]

Answer (score 2):

I pick an arbitrary amount of rep to decide what counts as "active" and then find the user page where that rep is displayed.  There are 35 users per page, so everyone above that page is "active".  Say I choose 100 rep.  The page where under 100 rep occurs is:

SO: [page 876](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=876), so about 30,700 active users

Meta: [page 185](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?page=185), so about 6,400 active users

Moms4mom: [page 4](http://moms4mom.com/users?page=4), so about 100 active users

Chiphacker: [page 3](http://moms4mom.com/users?page=4), so about 70 active users

The other metric I use is how many questions on the front page as a ratio of the oldest question on the front page.  Remember that the front page shows all post activity, answers as well as questions, so they aren't all 'new' questions.  Right now it's going to be low due to slower nighttime activity:

SO: 50 questions, oldest is 30 minutes old.  This gives you about 2,400 posts per day.

Meta: 50 questions, oldest is 13 hours, so about 92 posts per day

Moms4mom: 50 questions, oldest is Jan 20th, so about 6 posts per day

Chiphacker: 50 questions, oldest is Jan 8th, so about 2.5 posts per day

Between these two metrics, I feel I can size up a new stackexchange site quickly enough to decide whether it's worth sticking around, or whether I should spend my time elsewhere until the community has either matured or died off.

Answer (score 1):

Anton Geraschenko has [compiled some metrics](https://web.archive.org/web/20100329103144/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2750/yet-another-se-sites-statistics-tool-latest-data-jan-19) such as number of questions, answers, users, and activity of the Trilogy sites and various StackExchange sites.