# How many users does Stack Overflow currently have?

Tags: discussion, users

This gives an idea from 2008. I'm curious to see how many orders of magnitude it's changed since:
[Age distribution of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9822/age-distribution-of-stackoverflow-users)

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newest user id in the meta database is approximately [142539](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=newest).
For SO the id is currently around [261572](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=newest).

I very rough estimate, but at least that many have registered.

Comment: How did you find that?

Comment: Looking at the URL linking to the newest user (currently Brett Porter) on the Users page. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=newest

Comment: Oh I tried that but lots of them were missing like 32000, etc. I thought it cut off at 31999.

Comment: Note: now the correct link is http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=newusers

Answer (score 8):

There are 128 thousand stackoverflow users right now.  Users are periodically culled for users that have only 1 rep who don't return after a few months.  This can be determined by looking at the users page, and multiplying the number of user pages by 35 users per page.

If you look at users with 100 reputation or more (ie, those that are relatively 'active') you find there are [about 31 thousand active SO users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37379/community-size-of-a-stackexchange-or-stackoverflow-site/37388#37388).

Usually there are a small flurry of statistical type questions on Meta just after stack overflow data dumps, so if you bump this question just after January ends you may find someone willing to re-run that age query and give you a new graph.