# Reputation/Privileges when a beta becomes a fully fledged site

Tags: feature-request, reputation, privileges, beta-phase, faq-update-request

I have a minor curiosity on this, but I can't seem to find any documentation (at least on MSO or on the [Area51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)) about this specific point: What happens to your privileges when a site becomes a 'real' website/successfully graduates from the beta process?

I see that [rep requirements increase to full site levels](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64413/what-happens-when-the-public-beta-ends-for-a-stack-exchange-site-exactly). In other words, if I get to 1000 on a beta site, and can then make direct edits, and the minimum goes up, am I suddenly barred from that, even though I was already trusted to do this?

**When the site graduates, what happens?**

1. <strike>The rep requirement is increased, but I am grandfathered into and retain the privilege.</strike>
2. **The rep requirement is increased, and I lose the privilege.**
3. <strike>The rep requirement is increased, and my current reputation is scaled up to match, thereby preserving my privileges.</strike>

**EDIT:**

I understand point #2 to be correct.

Now that I know this, can we add this to the beta sites' and/or Area 51 FAQs or make this information more readily available in some other way (I'm still leaning toward the FAQs)?

Comment: Changes in privilege levels are documented in [this FAQ entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared). I think it implies that privileges can be lost when a site changes phase, but it never says that explicitly.

Comment: @PopularDemand Well, that's exactly my point! ;-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's no grandfathering of privileges of any kind. You'll immediately be held to the new privileges threshold and lose any privileges you no longer quality for. Similarly if you got a downvote at 3000 rep on a graduated site and now have 2998 rep, you'll (practically) immediately lose your close-vote ability.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, makes sense. Any way to get this added to an FAQ? *(Or does it already exist and I just missed it??)*

Comment: I am going to unaccept this answer in the hopes the question gets a little more attention/a formal response to the point about the FAQ. Sorry, Ben.

Comment: @Gaffi and thus **bounties** were born....

Comment: @IAMNOTONMETAATTHEMOMENT Yeah, but it shouldn't cost my extremely valuable Meta rep (only way I know how to procure glittery unicorns) to get things done!

Comment: @Gaffi if you want things done. You do them yourself. No matter how much it costs ^_^

Comment: @IAMNOTONMETAATTHEMOMENT But... [How do I shot web?](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/how-do-i-shot-web) No really, I can't fix the FAQ myself... can I?

Comment: @Gaffi alright; personally I'd have made a second, separate [feature-request] post though

Comment: Well, I went ahead and bounty'd up anyway. ;-)

Comment: Darn, I was afraid this would be the case.  It does make sense, though.  All the more incentive to keep earning that rep.

Answer (score 4):

So, I was unaware that this was a possibility for me, but I've updated [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/179372) with the info from [Ben's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139433/179372).

Thanks for the help, guys.