# Review count in ribbon less than actual posts to be reviewed

Tags: support, bug

I asked [this question which refers to Movies.SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1544/review-not-posting-in-the-ribbon) on [Meta.Movies.SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/) right after the site was promoted. I was asked by one of the mods to make the issue known so it might receive higher attention.

Basically, the review count which posts in the "ribbon" (I know, a Microsoft term for the top portion of the window) shows up with much less of a count than what is actually in the review queues. It can even show no review number, yet there be several entries to be reviewed. This has been happening since the site promotion which was around the end of January 2015.

I'm very used to having there be a number there and not having anything to review (I believe I even understand why this happens -- total to review vs. what I can actually review). The issue I'm describing here is quite the opposite.

Here are two screen captures to prove my point ...

Main screen (no review number posted):

[image]

Review screen with review-able items:

[image]

These two screen captures were taken within seconds of each other.

Talking with a mod on Movies.SE (through the Meta post), he does not see the issue. We thought it might have been a browser refresh issue, but I see this on whatever browser or machine I happen to be on at the time (iPad, Android phone, IE, Mozilla FireFox, Chrome). The mod doesn't see this and I do, plus I didn't see it before the site promotion (when I had full privileges). I'm sure it has something to do with permissions because of this.

Anyway, throwing it out there for consumption and some possible help.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is, until you have 10k, the number in the top bar (before "review") indicates how many there are *suggested edits* to review, and after you pass 10k, the total number of tasks in all the review queues.

The proof? There it is, hover the link:

> [image]

While on the site, where I have 10k (2k actually, but it's in beta):

> [image]

Also, looks like it's not really clear from the screenshots, [here's the post proving it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726) (so this question is going to be partly a dupe?).

Why did you see the number correctly when the site was in beta? Because while in beta, the 10k tools are obtained at 2k rep (and in private beta, at 1k), and after the site graduates, [your privileges are recalculated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139432/reputation-privileges-when-a-beta-becomes-a-fully-fledged-site). Why does the mod see the number? Because, well, they have 10k and, moreover, they are a mod.

Comment: Can you cite some canonical source that clarifies that the review counter *only* shows suggested edits and nothing else for <10k (which would seem rather strange, since he can already review other things as well)?

Comment: @ChristianRau done :)

Comment: Well, if that is really the case, then that's a sure feature-request, as showing suggested edits only seems completely useless.

Comment: Your explanation makes no sense to me. You place this solely at the feet of edits. The whole idea of the "number" in the first place (from my POV) is to provide you with an indicator there is something which needs to be done in the review queues ... *all of the review queues*.

Comment: @Paul the original answer is just because I know it - I wasn't going to confuse you or post info I'm not 111% sure to be correct. Once possible, I'll add more meaningful screenshots.

Comment: @Paul Found additional explanation: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726

Comment: Are you suggesting this should be a feature request and not considered a bug? Like Christian said, completely useless in its current state.

Comment: I'm not suggesting anything - it's feature as stated in the answer I linked. Despite the behavior of this number being a bit strange, it doesn't really disturb me.