# Multiple answers to the same question should show up separately in a user profile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page

We suspended a user on Programmers yesterday because all of his answers were directly copied and pasted from other sites without even a hint of attribution.

This morning I found out that we missed removing one of those answers. This user posted two answers to the same question and I think what happened is that we saw the first answer and removed it, but he managed to post the second one before we issued the suspension. Although, looking at timestamps, maybe we just didn't notice the second answer.

His profile looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

The line for "when to use C over C++, and C++ over C" shows two answers with a combined score of -4, but it's not immediately noticeable that there are two answers there and one is still visible. It looks like both answers are deleted. (To be honest, I missed the `(2)` entirely at first but that's probably just me.)

There is also no way to jump directly to the second answer from that page.

I think the answers should appear separately if possible. This would provide a clear picture in terms of deleted posts. Maybe the collapsed/expanded answer view could be toggled.

Failing that, maybe we can turn `(2)` into a link to the second answer and if there are more answers for some reason, present them as linkified `(3)`, `(4)`, etc., on the same line.

This is not a big deal under normal circumstances, but when dealing with a malicious user it would be handy to have a clearer picture of their contributions.

P.S [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2747/stop-grouping-together-multiple-answers-to-the-same-question-in-user-profile) already requested this, but it's two years old and I wanted to bring up a new case for this feature.

Comment: Nope, you're not the only one who missed the `(2)`.

Comment: Yeah, the best you can do currently is use advanced search to get the list of answers in that question, which is tedious. I can think of a reason why it might be done this way, but if it could be changed having an expando-arrrow like the reputation rollups might be nice. Failing that, having the number link directly to the advanced search query might be alright too.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like it was finally implemented lots of time ago :)

> [image]