# Add first few words from answer to text shown for questions answered in user's Activity / Summary tab

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, reputation-summary, answer-summary

The [user's activity summary tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=summary) shows multiple answers to the same question ([which is permissible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice) in certain circumstances) in a manner which makes it difficult to tell which one is which since they are [labeled solely by the text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108887/multiple-answers-to-the-same-question-should-show-up-separately-in-a-user-profil?noredirect=1&lq=1) of the question:

[image: Answers and Reputation]

This ambiguity carries over to the Reputation section.

If the first few words from your answer appeared after the question text we would be able to differentiate one from another:

[image: Answers and Reputation_Differentiation]

Comment: That's way more detail than necessary on this page. I know from the profile that their best/newest/most recently active posts are *{these questions}* and *{answers to these other questions}*. If I care that much about the actual content, I can click the link that is already present, without trying to either read a tiny font or having to scroll the page again to see the next three records in the list.

Comment: I don't want to make a long list of specific examples, you can see one above; others are on [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/), or even [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/). No one is suggesting a tiny font or scrolling. If you don't like the idea that's OK. Maybe we can overcomplicate it by adding opt-in and bigger fonts - to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple answers to a question from the same users isn't that common. Meta oddness aside, there's literally one site where there's a legitimate need to post multiple answers to a question.

I suspect this would add clutter.

Comment: PPCG, Maths, MO, Worldbuilding, Puzzling, TWP, and I'm sure there are more. All have a swath of questions where a single user could post multiple answers legitimately.